# Python - How to access a fixture attribute

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to access an attribute that is inside a fixture, how do I access it.

contest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def numbers():
    one = 1
    two = 2
    total = one+two
    return numbers
```

num.py

```
def test(numbers):
    print("total = ",numbers.total)
```

getting the below error for above
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'total'`

Comment: `return total` So return something that has attribute, not an int.

Comment: Your function is returning the total aka `one + two` which is an integer. When you try to do `numbers.one` you trying to do `int.one` which doesn't exist as integers are just primitives. You need to re-assess what you are trying to do and make sure a fixture is what you need

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Why do you think your code should work? What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to use fixtures, but based on the example it looks like you want a fixture to return an object with some data that you can just access as attributes using the dot notation.  In that case, you could create an empty class, and have the fixture return an instance of that class, as follows:

```
import pytest

class TestData():
    pass

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def numbers():
    data = TestData()
    data.one = 1
    data.two = 2
    data.total = data.one + data.two
    return data

def test_nums(numbers):
    assert numbers.one == 1
    assert numbers.two == 2
    assert numbers.total == 3
```

However, this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as you haven't really explained what you're trying to do and why.

If you really just want basic integers like 1 and 2 available in test, just use the literals.  If you want to pass different sets of literal integers to identical tests, consider using [@pytest.mark.parameterize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/parametrize.html).

Fixtures are useful when you need to have some more complex data set up for multiple test cases - for example, you need a collection of objects which will be referenced by multiple tests.

Answer (score -1):

```
def test(numbers):
print(numbers())
```

A variable just declared inside a function is not accessable outside of the function.